# How do I force MediaWiki to evaluate a function with high priority?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

I have a persistent issue with a default tag in a "show on select" form.

```
<div id="test-a">

{{#show: MyPage | ?MyAttribute}}
{|class="formtable"
! A:
| {{{field|input type = text|default= {{#show SomePage | ?SomeAttribute}} }}}
|-
! B:
| {{{field|input type = text|default= {{#show SomeOtherPage | ?SomeOtherAttribute}}  }}}
|}
</div>
```

Instead of evaluating the #show commands, the fields get defaulted to "{{#show SomePage | ?SomeAttribute}}" and "{{#show SomeOtherPage | ?SomeOtherAttribute}}".

How do I force MediaWiki to evaluated the #show function no matter what?

Comment: Can we get a link to see this in action... Your details seem to be lacking... Which version of MW are you running? Is it a semantic MW installation? What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: You are missing some `:`s there after `#show`.

Answer (score 0):

As Tgr said, you are missing some `:`s there after `#show`. Fix the syntax and it will work, it's not a matter of priority.